# How can I get grid texture for game level design?

Tags: modeling, materials, shaders, world, shader-nodes

I am planning to make a open-world game using blender. I cannot find a single tutorial or question related to white boxing, which is very important for game level design.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Is there any shader that can do this or do I have to look into something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Checkered Texture]

Hey there, Is this the sort of thing you need? It can be scaled with the Value node and the contrast adjusted with the mix slider.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the checker texture shader node, it gives a very similar result.

Comment: Nice idea :). Could you please illustrate your answer with some images? Just so the OP knows how to use it.

Comment: When I write this, I was in mobile and unable to, so I will elaborate asa I’m back.

Comment: Hello! This is a really nice grid pattern shader but I want the size of a single square in the texture to be the same as I scale it up or apply it to another mesh.

Comment: Try using us coordinates, and scale the cubes in edit mode instead of normally, pics following

Answer (score 0):

If you want the checkers to always be the same size, use object instead of generated coordinates and scale or edit the shape in edit mode. If you want to use this material for multiple objects, simply select the material in the dropdown menu. The node setup looks like this:

[image]

The "scale" node is actually a value node, which I just renamed to make it look cleaner (f2 is the shortcut), and I also added a math node set to "ceil", so the sclaling is snappier. Alternatively it can be set to "floor", "round", "truncate" or completely removed.
The node in the very end is a MixRGB node set to "overlay".

If you want the objects to interact with light & shadows more realistically, add either a Diffuse BSDF or a Principled BSDF (takes longer to calculate) like this:

[image]

I hope this is what you needed!